# How can I disable "Welcome to mapbox" marker

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Every time I open the mapbox map (paid plan) there is a "welcome to mapbox" marker. How can I disable / hide this?

This is my code to create the map:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'xxx.yyy')
                .setView([51.163375, 10.447683], 6)
                .addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('xxx.yyy'));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a very simple solution. Just wait!
After 24 hours, the marker was hidden.

Answer (score 6):

You have to go into your projects (https://www.mapbox.com/projects/) > data > hamburger menu (3 stacked lines)

You'll see it listed as a feature and can delete it using the trash icon. I'm guessing it's a stand in on your first project as I just had the same question on my own first project.